# QFtp Warning QIODevice::read (QTcpSocket, QFtpDTP

Tags: qt5

**QFtp Ftp;**

When i have Ftp loggedIn and i try to get a file that does not exist on the server using
**Ftp.get(RemoteFile, LocalFile.data());** i received a warning
I know it is because of writting direct to data of LocalFile.
This is the **warning:
QIODevice::read (QTcpSocket, "QFtpDTP Passive state socket"): device not open**
What is the best way to treat this warning?
I tried **Try Catch(...)** to fix the issue and still happenning.

Answer (score 0):

Forget about. I use the list command before the get to check if file was there and avoid the issue.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I did a FTP.list(RemoteDirectory) and if the file is there i call FTP.get(RemoteDirectoy, localFile.data()), if is not there i do not call The FTP.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).